# Creating a local rpmforge/repoforge mirror?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, repository, rpm

I make good use of [RPMforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) for my production CentOS systems. I have local repositories for the main CentOS distribution and updates, however, recent automated kickstart installs are starting to hang on downloads from slower RPMforge mirrors. I've tried limiting to specific RPMforge mirrors and also using the yum fastestmirror plugin. I'd like to establish a local RPMforge repository, but don't know if this is a common practice. I'd be interested in mirroring the EL5 and EL6 repositories.

Does anyone here do this in their own environments? How much space should be budgeted for such a mirror? Or is this idea overkill?

***Edit:*** 

Some installation-time debugging seems to show that many of the RPMforge mirrors are outdated or inaccessible. I did find some references to `mrepo` as a potential solution, though.

Comment: enable keep cache in the yum config files for the external repos, and transfer back those packages into your own internal repo. In time youll get a nice mirror of just what you need, and if you setup repo priority, it'll save you alot of downloading.

Comment: You can also use a proxy/cache that is dedicated for this (to minimize the cache misses).

Comment: I'm not even as concerned about the downloads (as we have plenty of bandwidth), other that there seem to be some major latency issues using the preferred mirror.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are mirroring RPMForge form this server:

mirror="rsync://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/dag"

It's quite fast and reliable.For EL5 it takes 13G, I assume it would be the same for 6

It's common practice but it depends how many machines do you have. We are serving our internal mirrort to 3000+ hosts, so it absolutely makes sense